# Arranging div one below the other with different hight (mega menu)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a problem with a menu which has a lot of sub menus. The menu is generated dynamically and I don't know the right number of the categories and subcategories either. 
At the moment when the menu is opened, the columns of the second row become in chaos. The same is happening when I resize the screen, instead of going one under the other.

In the example given bellow, the columns of the first row are ok, and the last two of the second row are ok too. The problematic ones are "Adhesives" and "Cutting Instruments".
Instead of going under "Paintig" and "Colouring" the are in the same line where "Creativity" ends.

I have to mention that I can't put two categories in the one div, because in that case when resizing the screen the categories wouldn't be one under the other.
Here is my example and I would be very thankful if someone helps me with this.

DEMO

```
<http://jsfiddle.net/rjkbw6to/1/>
```

Comment: In this case, I'd say the design is the problem. Even if the tops and bottoms of the columns touched, it would still be bad UX in my options. I would suggest limiting each column to a number of options, and having a collapsible 'more' option at the bottom of each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#mz_primaryNav ul>li ul li {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

#mz_primaryNav ul>li ul li>div {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: This will arrange second row in same line (the heights height) will be beginning of second row of divs. This is what i would like to get. https://imgur.com/a/IkzBy43